# Using TeX to Typeset Indian Raga Music Forms

Tags: subscripts, superscripts, music

I could use any input on this one. I am trying to typeset the various raga forms and scales that I am learning in my sitar class. I need to be able to put from one to three dots (not periods) over and under the letters. In addition, I need to be able to add subscripted information. For example, I have the first note of my scale as Sah. I would like to put to dots over it and under it put the the fingering keys for example rah/i  indicating the direction of the stroke and indicating that the index finger is on that fret. Any ideas? I am only now getting into musical typesetting and have not yet integrated it into TeX or LaTex. I am interested in any help and insights that can be offered here. In advance thank you.

Comment: i think the appearance of what you're looking for is unfamiliar to many readers of this forum.  if you could make a drawing and post a scan, that would be helpful.

Comment: As far as I understand, Raagas can be notated using several systems, one using words and one using western scales (http://raag-hindustani.com/Notation.html). If you want to notate using the western system I would suggest **not** using latex. It is possible using Lilypond (which is to much work implementing into latex) or ABC (which looks awful) but neither is satisfactory in conjunction with latex. You could use Lilypond/Sibelius/Finale externally and simply export/import graphics files, which i do. It is quick and simple. If you are planning to use words, a simple table will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

An example on how to use the table using symbols both for the dots and playing direction (arbitrary):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

Using mathmode:
\vspace{10 mm}

\begin{tabular}{c | c | c | c} 
\(\overset{.}{Ta'}\) & \(\overset{.}{Ke`}\) & \(\overset{.}{Di}\) & \(\overset{.}{Mi}\) \\ 
\end{tabular}

\vspace{10 mm}

Or two lines:
\vspace{10 mm}

\begin{tabular}{c | c | c | c} 
. & .. & ... & . \\ 
Ta' & Ke` & Di & Mi \\ 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]